# MagneticField property of CMDeviceMotion incorrect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-motion, magnetometer

I have been experimenting with CMDeviceMotion, and especially with startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame. The magneticField values in that don't seem correct to me.

For example, if I do:

```
CMDeviceMotion *manager = [[CMDeviceMotion alloc] init];
manager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.1;
[manager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryCorrectedZVertical toQueue:queue withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
    CMMagneticField fld = motion.magneticField.field;
    NSLog( @"%5.1f %5.1f %5.1f", fld.x, fld.y, fld.z );
    [self handleDeviceMotion:manager.deviceMotion];
}];
```

it shows a magneticField vector with a size of about 50, but almost aligned with gravity. That is, when the device is lying flat on a table, x and y are close to zero, and z is close to -50, independent of how I rotate the device.

The 50 would be correct in size for the Earth's magnetic field (according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field) should be between between 25 and 65 micro Tesla), but the direction of the vector seems all wrong. I was wondering whether:

- It is something peculiar at my location only (Stockholm, Sweden), or
- The magneticField property shows remaining magnetic field without the earth's field, or
- This is bug

Do you have similar experiences with the magneticField property?

Comment: At least for part of your question, the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreMotion/Reference/CMDeviceMotion_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMDeviceMotion/magneticField) are your friend: "... gives you the total magnetic field in the device’s vicinity without device bias... these values reflect the earth’s magnetic field plus surrounding fields, minus device bias."

Comment: True, but the real behaviour does not seem to be according to the docs...

Comment: Your question inspired me to play around with the magnetometer some myself... I tried this code (not using the reference frame from your answer since I'm interested in device-relative field direction), but all I see is <0,0,0>. Am I missing something that's not in your excerpt?

Comment: Turns out you still want a reference frame even if you want device-relative direction... the default `CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical` never calibrates the sensor, as best I can tell, but `CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryCorrectedZVertical` starts reporting real data after a few seconds / if you wave the device around some.

Comment: That is correct. XArbitrayZVertical never switches the magnetometer on, because it is not needed to establish the reference frame. The other three options all produce magnetometer samples. It should give proper samples immediately, but sometimes it takes some more time, especially if you are inside with lots of metal/computers, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the mystery is solved.

I now used a reference frame CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical, which gives similar results to the ...XArbirtraryCorrectedZVertical that I used before. Then I calculated how the magneticField vector is positioned with respect to gravity, by rotating it back to the referenceFrame using the given attitude.

It turns out the magneticField is pretty stably pointing 5 degrees east of true north, but with an angle of about 73 degrees into the ground. And that is ***exactly*** according to expectation for my location in Sweden, according to [this map](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/WMM/data/WMM2010/WMM2010_I_MERC.pdf).

Comment: Yeah. They don't teach you that one at school :-) Most of Earth's magnetic field vector points directly in to the ground – at least, it does where I live (in Britain).